# Setting up the Scalable, Fault tolerant Kafka Cluster on AWS autoscale Group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

I am trying to setup a fault tolerant Kafka cluster on AWS Auto scale group. I have automated it using chef. Initial Size of the cluster will be 3 nodes. But based on the load, it should be able to horizontally scale, also it should be fault tolerant( i have the replication factor of 3 for all the topics). i have set auto scale settings as (min 3 node , max 10 nodes, desired 3 node).

Whenever the new node comes up in the Auto scale group, it should be able to share the load, also if one of the nodes goes down, the new node which has come up as replacement should function seamlessly, by getting all the data of the old node.

Thanks for taking time to read, appreciate any help.

Regards,
Sagar